# How can I pass in text rather than a file as a variable

Tags: perl, shell, command-line, terminal

I want to pass text in as a variable rather than a file.
I am not sure how to explain this well only with an example.

I have a perl script with usage as follows printme.pl [file]
I want to run without passing in a file and just passing text.

```
echo print_me | perl printme.pl
```

rather than doing

```
perl printme.pl textfile.txt
```

I am trying to run a perl script that takes a text file as a variable and outputs using echo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bash (amongst other shells) has a feature called [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution). In this feature, you can add some shell code that outputs to stdout and have the shell treat it like a file.

In your case, you would write:

```
perl printme.pl <(echo "hello world")
```

Perl will receive in $ARGV[0] a filename that looks something like /dev/fd/63 from which it can read the line "hello world\n"

Comment: When I do that I get the error when I try to open a log file in my script. `open($logfile,">","$cruftDirectory/indent.log")` The script dies.

Comment: What is `$cruftDirectory`? If it's the dirname of $ARGV[0], you'll have to pick a different directory.

Comment: It is just the current directory.

Comment: Catch the error and display it: `open $logfile, '>', "$cruftDirectory/indent.log" or die "can't open: $!";`